# RequestCaptureMediaPermission for WKWebView in Maui iOS

Tags: ios, maui, wkwebview

In Microsoft Learn (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167987/how-to-fix-double-permission-popup-in-xamarin-ios) a solution is given to reduce the number of prompts for camera and microphone permission when WebRTC is used in Xamarin iOS. I could not get it working on Maui IOS. I have also opened a ticket in GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17431)

The API RequestMediaCapturePermission is not called at all. I am not sure where is the error in my code in the small project that I have uploaded in GitHub. Greatly appreciate any help, especially from those who managed to get it working.

Thank you.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue and it could be that `RequestMediaCapturePermission` is not inserted into MAUI iOS repo. Since you have logged a new issue on GitHub, you can continue following up there. Thanks!

Comment: That is what I suspected. The RequestMediaCapturePermission cannot be found in MAUI repo at all. Unfortunately, the MAUI team has placed my bug report to backlog. This means we won't know when it will be fixed. Is there a way I can debug this issue, fix it, and update a fix into MAUI repo? (I don't know how to compile and use a local copy of MAUI repo.)

Comment: Thanks for the update, you can refer to the answer below on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Handlers/WebView/WebViewHandler.cs#L32, the IWebViewHandler on iOS has been defined like below:

```
#elif __IOS__
            [nameof(WKUIDelegate)] = MapWKUIDelegate,
#endif
```

To call the `RequestMediaCapturePermission`, you may change the `"PermissionRequest"` to `nameof(WKUIDelegate)`:

```
#if IOS || MACCATALYST
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.Add(nameof(WKUIDelegate), (handler, view) =>
            {
                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(15, 0))
                {
                  MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                  {
                    handler.PlatformView.UIDelegate = new WebViewUIDelegate();
                  });
                }
            });
        return builder.Build();
#endif
```

```
  [Export("webView:requestMediaCapturePermissionForOrigin:initiatedByFrame:type:decisionHandler:")]
  public override void RequestMediaCapturePermission(WKWebView webView, WKSecurityOrigin origin, WKFrameInfo frame, WKMediaCaptureType type, Action<WKPermissionDecision> decisionHandler)
 {
      decisionHandler(WKPermissionDecision.Grant);
      base.RequestMediaCapturePermission(webView, origin, frame, type, decisionHandler );
  }
```

Comment: As pointed out in the link to github, WKUIDelegate is mapped to MapWKUIDelegate is available for IOS only. Therefore, as I have tested, it is not working on MACCATALYST. What should I do to change #elif __IOS__ to #elif __IOS__ || __MACCATALYST__?

Comment: @TekMun You can try to change it to  #elif **IOS** || **MACCATALYST** to see if it works. It it doesn't work ,you can report to:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17431.

Comment: The code is inside the main dotnet MAUI repository. How do I compile a local copy of dotnet Maui?